# Find the time point in a column while reading the maximum in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, max

I have a general problem where I want to find a value in a certain column (for example A) and once I found it I want to read the value that is the same row but in a different column (for example B). Note that I usually have 300 columns that have a long name (for example TIME=2020-02-26 13:13:29)

This is how some of my data looks like:

```
Time (min)  Fluo at 505 nm  Fluo at 483 nm
0   6009.5287   7779.00879
10  5843.4019   7579.47199
20  5767.2625   7516.12249
30  5744.7249   7508.69999
40  5757.8681   7505.58810
50  5725.5031   7477.69310
60  5735.7887   7457.96376
70  5738.6775   7459.54250
80  5728.7831   7435.29809
90  5689.1200   7436.50999
```

I want to find the maximum value in 'Fluo at 505 nm' and 'Fluo at 483 nm' and then find the time point where I have the maximum.

So far I have this (I also tried with `.max()` and `.idxmax()` but it obviously gives the same result).:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.loadtxt('TestData.txt', skiprows=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
Fluo = data[:,1:]
df_max = np.amax(Fluo, axis = 0)
df_position = np.argmax(Fluo, axis = 0)
print(df_position)
```

The problem is that this way I get the index where the maximum is but not the time point.

This is the output:

```
[224 228 235 224 232 236 230 230 232 223 231 233 221 220 225 229 232 232 ... 193 196 196 204 190
 196 194]
```

The problem seems so easy but I have been stuck on it for more then a week. Hope to find an easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `idxmax` to get the index of the maximum value in each column and create a new Series from the result using the time column as the name of the series and the remaining columns as its index.

In my example below, I modified your sample data so that the max value of the second column (`Fluo at 483 nm`) is on the last row (`Time (min)` value of `90`).  Having the max value on the first row is a bit confusing for an example, as both index 0 and time 0 are the same.  Having max values on different makes the example more realistic.

```
df.iat[-1, -1] = 10000
>>> pd.Series(
        df[df.columns[0]].loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax()].tolist(), 
        index=df.columns[1:],
        name=df.columns[0]
    )
Fluo at 505 nm     0
Fluo at 483 nm    90
Name: Time (min), dtype: int64
```

Comment: I have tried using this but I get the following error: `
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type 

KeyError: 'Time (min)' `.

Comment: Perhaps you column name is slightly different or has leading/trailing whitespace?  You could instead just use the first column (time) as follows: `df[df.columns[0]].loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax()].tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.idxmax()` and then use the index with `.loc[]` to get the value you want. For example:

```
data = [{'time': 0, 'fluo1': 6009.5287, 'fluo2': 7779.008790000001},
 {'time': 10, 'fluo1': 5843.4019, 'fluo2': 7579.471990000001},
 {'time': 20, 'fluo1': 5767.2625, 'fluo2': 7516.122490000001},
 {'time': 30, 'fluo1': 5744.7249, 'fluo2': 7508.699990000001},
 {'time': 40, 'fluo1': 5757.8681, 'fluo2': 7505.5881},
 {'time': 50, 'fluo1': 5725.5031, 'fluo2': 7477.6931},
 {'time': 60, 'fluo1': 5735.7887, 'fluo2': 7457.96376},
 {'time': 70, 'fluo1': 5738.6775, 'fluo2': 7459.5425},
 {'time': 80, 'fluo1': 5728.7831, 'fluo2': 7435.29809},
 {'time': 90, 'fluo1': 5689.12, 'fluo2': 7436.5099900000005}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.loc[df['fluo2'].idxmax(), 'time']
```

Comment: If I copy and paste your code it works, but if I try applying it to my data (that I have imported with .loadtxt and converted in .DataFrame) it gives the same error: 
 _ File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type

KeyError: 'Fluo1' _.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you use `pandas` to read the file. `pd.read_table('TestData.txt'')` or `pd.read_csv('TestData.txt', sep='\t')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get both values in a one liner as,

```
df['Time (min)'].loc[[df['Fluo at 505 nm'].idxmax(),df['Fluo at 483 nm'].idxmax()]]
```

Comment: Also with this code I get the same error: `
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type 

KeyError: 'Time (min)'` . The other problem of this code is that I have to type all of the column and in most of my data I have 300 columns with very long names so in those cases this would take too much.